# multi-GPU tower; ValueError: None values not supported

Tags: tensorflow

I've tried to use multi-GPU tower defs from cifar10_train_multiGPU.py to LeNet with MNIST data in jupyter-notebook environments.

-but, I don't use movingaveragedecay for losses and variables

But, implementing those defs occurs errors and I don't know why.
Please, help me to understand and ,if you have, give me better templates for fully using GPUs.

---

**Here is where the error comes from.**

```
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    # Setting optimizer
    optimizer = OPTIMIZER('GD')

    # Calculate the gradients for each model tower.
    total_grads = []
    for i in range(n_GPU):
        with tf.device('/gpu:%d' % i):
            with tf.name_scope('%s_%d' % (TOWER_NAME, i)) as scope:
                tower_loss = TOWER_LOSS(scope)
                tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
                tower_grads = optimizer.compute_gradients(tower_loss)
                print(tower_grads)
                total_grads.append(tower_grads)
    grads = AVERAGE_GRADIENTS(total_grads)

    train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads, global_step=global_step)
```

---

When I'm print(tower_grads), the result from first device is good.
BUT, after then, the None appears.

---

[(, ), (, ), (, ), (, ), (, ), (, ), (, ), (, )]
[(None, ), (None, ), (None, ), (None, ), (None, ), (None, ), (None, ), (None, ), (, ), (, ), (, ), (, ), (, ), (, ), (, ), (, )]

---

So, I changed the code to calculate just loss in their own scope.

```
tower_grads = optimizer.compute_gradients(tower_loss, tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope))
```

Then, the codes can be run.
BUT, the losses are not going to be minimized.

> Iter :100     Total_loss: 2.62306
>   Iter :200   Total_loss: 2.67096
>   Iter :300   Total_loss: 2.82596
>   Iter :400   Total_loss: 2.76608
>   Iter :500   Total_loss: 2.71014
>   Iter :600   Total_loss: 2.79502
>   Iter :700   Total_loss: 2.8309
>   Iter :800   Total_loss: 2.89564
>   Iter :900   Total_loss: 2.75665
>   Iter :1000  Total_loss: 2.75197
>   Iter :1100  Total_loss: 2.90878
>   Iter :1200  Total_loss: 2.6832
>   Iter :1300  Total_loss: 2.80052

---

Here are full codes.

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, IMAGE_SIZE*IMAGE_SIZE*IMAGE_CHANNELS], name='x_raw')
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, LABEL_SIZE], name='label')

# Global_step
global_step = tf.get_variable('global_step', [], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0), trainable=False)

def INFERENCE(_X):
    _x_reshaped = tf.reshape(_X, [-1, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_CHANNELS], name='x_reshaped')
    C1 = _CONV(_x_reshaped, 5, 64)
    S1 = _MAXPOOL(C1)
    C2 = _CONV(S1, 5, 128)
    S2 = _MAXPOOL(C2)

    _size = S2.get_shape()[1].value
    _channel_size = S2.get_shape()[3].value
    x_flatten = tf.reshape(S2, [-1, _size*_size*_channel_size])  
    FC3 = tf.nn.relu(_LINEAR(x_flatten, n_out=1024))
    _softmax_linear = _LINEAR(FC3, LABEL_SIZE)
    return _softmax_linear

def _WEIGHT_WITH_WD(_SHAPE):
    _initial = tf.truncated_normal(_SHAPE, stddev=0.05)
    _weight = tf.Variable(_initial, name='weight', trainable=True)
    return _weight

def _BIAS(_SHAPE):
    _initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=_SHAPE)  # dead cell 방지
    return tf.Variable(_initial, name='bias', trainable=True)

def _CONV(_X, kernel_size, out_channel_size, stride_size=1, wd=WD_CONV):
    _in_channels = _X.get_shape()[3].value  
    _kernel_shape = [kernel_size, kernel_size, _in_channels, out_channel_size]
    _kernel = _WEIGHT_WITH_WD(_kernel_shape)
    _stride = [1, stride_size, stride_size, 1]
    _conv = tf.nn.conv2d(_X, _kernel, _stride, padding='SAME')
    _conv_activated = tf.nn.relu(_conv + _BIAS([out_channel_size]))
    return _conv_activated

def _MAXPOOL(_X, kernel_size=2, stride_size=2):
    _kernel_shape = [1, kernel_size, kernel_size, 1]
    _stride = [1, stride_size, stride_size, 1]
    _max_pool = tf.nn.max_pool(_X, _kernel_shape, _stride, padding='SAME')
    return _max_pool

def _LINEAR(_X, n_out):
    _weight = _WEIGHT_WITH_WD([_X.get_shape()[1].value, n_out])
    _bias = _BIAS([n_out])
    _linear = tf.matmul(_X, _weight) + _bias
    return _linear

def OPTIMIZER(optimizer='GD'):
    _lr = LR
    _optimizer_dic = {'GD':tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(_lr), 'ADAM':tf.train.AdamOptimizer(_lr)}
    _opt = _optimizer_dic[optimizer]
    return _opt

def TOTAL_LOSS(logits, labels):
    with tf.name_scope('Loss') as scope:
        _cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, labels, name='cross_entropy_per_example')
        _cross_entropy_mean = tf.reduce_mean(_cross_entropy, name='cross_entropy_per_batch')
        tf.add_to_collection('losses', _cross_entropy_mean)
        _total_loss = tf.add_n(tf.get_collection('losses'), name='total_loss')
        return _total_loss

def TOWER_LOSS(scope):    
    _logits = INFERENCE(x)
    _ = TOTAL_LOSS(_logits, y_)
    _tower_loss_list = tf.get_collection('losses', scope)
    _tower_loss = tf.add_n(_tower_loss_list, name='tower_loss')

    # Compute the moving average of all individual losses and the total loss.
    loss_averages = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(0.9, name='avg')
    loss_averages_op = loss_averages.apply(_tower_loss_list + [_tower_loss])

    with tf.control_dependencies([loss_averages_op]):
        _tower_loss = tf.identity(_tower_loss)

    return _tower_loss

def AVERAGE_GRADIENTS(total_grads):
    average_grads = []  
    for grad_n_vars in zip(*total_grads): 
        grads = []
        for g, _ in grad_n_vars: 
            expanded_g = tf.expand_dims(g, 0)
            grads.append(expanded_g)
        grad = tf.concat(0, grads)  
        grad = tf.reduce_sum(grad, reduction_indices=0)  
        var = grad_n_vars[0][1] 
        grad_n_var = (grad, var)
        average_grads.append(grad_n_var)
    return average_grads    

with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    # Setting optimizer
    optimizer = OPTIMIZER('GD')

    # Calculate the gradients for each model tower.
    total_grads = []
    for i in range(n_GPU):
        with tf.device('/gpu:%d' % i):
            with tf.name_scope('%s_%d' % (TOWER_NAME, i)) as scope:
                tower_loss = TOWER_LOSS(scope)
                tf.get_variable_scope().reuse_variables()
                tower_grads = optimizer.compute_gradients(tower_loss, tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES, scope))
                total_grads.append(tower_grads)
    grads = AVERAGE_GRADIENTS(total_grads)

    train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads, global_step=global_step)

    ## Launch the graph
    with tf.Session(config=CONFIG) as sess:
        sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

        # Start the queue runners.
        tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess)

        # training
        for i in range(MAX_ITER):
            if i%PRINT_BY != 0 or i==0:
                tr_x, tr_y_ = mnist.train.next_batch(BATCH_SIZE)
                sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={x:tr_x, y_:tr_y_})

            else:
                ## print
                gstep, tower_loss_ = sess.run([global_step, tower_loss], feed_dict={x:tr_x, y_:tr_y_})
                print("GStep: %d \tIter :%d \tTotal_loss: %g" \
                      %(gstep, i, tower_loss_))
```

Answer (score 2):

From your output, it looks like each tower is creating a new set of variables:

```
[(, ), (, ), (, ), (, ), (, ), (, ), (, ), (, )]
[(None, ), (None, ), (None, ), (None, ), (None, ), (None, ), (None, ), (None, ), (, ), (, ), (, ), (, ), (, ), (, ), (, ), (, )]
```

Note that there are twice as many variables (16 vs. 8) in the output for the second tower, and the first 8 variables have no gradients in the second tower.

There are two potential fixes:

1. Ensure that your `TOWER_LOSS()` function includes `with tf.variable_scope(...):` blocks. See  the [`cifar10.inference()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/5508516010b539709da6a75bfbe5a3fd1a944b75/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10.py#L173) function for an example. You need to create a `tf.variable_scope()` to use variable sharing.
2. Use [`tf.get_variable()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#get_variable) instead of [`tf.Variable()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Variable) to ensure that the variables are shared where possible. Here's an [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/5508516010b539709da6a75bfbe5a3fd1a944b75/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10.py#L108) of how this is done in CIFAR-10.

For more details on sharing variables, see to [how-to guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/how_tos/variable_scope/index.html#sharing-variables).

Comment: Thanks to your help, the (None, ~) issue is solved.
BUT, the loss are not decreased by step..